# Animated.ScrollView is not scrolling horizontally, only on Android with using the scrollTo() method

Tags: android, react-native, animation, scrollview

I created to scroll multi-pages using *Animated.ScrollView*. It is working properly on iOS, but it got stuck on Android.

Here is my CustomPagerView component:

```
import { StyleSheet, Animated, Dimensions, Platform} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('screen');

export const CustomPagerView = ({
  scrollViewRef,
  pageNumber,
  scrollX,
  setCurrentIndex,
  children,
  updateCurrentIndex,
}) => {
  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      ref={scrollViewRef}
      bounces={false}
      hozinontal={true}
      style={{flex: 1}}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        width: width * pageNumber,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexGrow: 1,
      }}
      disableIntervalMomentum={false}
      decelerationRate={'normal'}
      showPageIndicator={false}
      pagingEnabled
      onMomentumScrollEnd={updateCurrentIndex}
      onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: scrollX}}}], {
        useNativeDriver: false,
      })}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      scrollEnabled={false}
      onScrollEndDrag={() => {
        console.log('scrollViewRef.current>>>', scrollViewRef.current);
        setCurrentIndex(scrollViewRef.current);
      }}
      scrollEventThrottle={400}>
      {children}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width,
    height,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingBottom: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 40 : 0,
  },
});
```

Calling component like that:

```
          <CustomPagerView
            scrollViewRef={scrollViewRef}
            pageNumber={3}
            scrollX={scrollX}
            setCurrentIndex={setCurrentIndex}
            updateCurrentIndex={updateCurrentIndex}>
            <View key="0" style={{width, flex: 1}}>
              <Component1 />
            </View>
            <View key="1" style={{width, flex: 1}}>
              <Component2 key="1" navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
            <View key="2" style={{width, flex: 1}}>
              <Component3 navigation={navigation} />
            </View>
          </CustomPagerView>
```

Functions or other elements for using that CustomPagerView is located in the parent Component and defined like that:

```
    const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const scrollViewRef = useRef();
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    const {setTitle} = useContext(ReportTitleContext);
    const [currentPageNumber, setCurrentPageNumber] = useState(0);

    let pagerViewRef = useRef();

    const updateCurrentIndex = (e) => {
      const contentOffsetX = Number(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
      const updatedCurrentIndex = Math.round(contentOffsetX / width);
      setCurrentIndex(updatedCurrentIndex);
    };
    const onNextPageHandler = () => {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1);
      setTitle(headerText[currentIndex + 1]);
      // scrollX.setValue((currentIndex + 1) * width);
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        x: (currentIndex + 1) * width,
        y: 0,
        animated: true,
      });
    };

    const onPreviousPageHandler = () => {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1);
      setTitle(headerText[currentIndex - 1]);
      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
        x: (currentIndex - 1) * width,
        y: 0,
        animated: true,
      });
    };
```

How can I do it?

Comment: *"Any idea?"* is not a real question. [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: Have you solved this? Having the exact same issue...

Comment: Yes. I have mistyped horizontal property like that hozinontal={true}. Look at your code carefully. I hope it will help you